# Add Link Category on Activation?

Tags: plugin-development, link-category, activation

Is it possible to add a link category on plugin activation?

What I mean is the Links section, as you know by default it has the Blogroll link category. I want to add a new link category when my plugin is activated, is there a quick and easy way to do this? What is the best method to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link category is a simple taxonomy just like categories , named: `link_category` so to add one you can use [**`wp_insert_term()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) eg:

```
wp_insert_term(
  'My link category', // the term 
  'link_category', // the taxonomy
  array(
    'description'=> 'this is a description.',
    'slug' => 'my-link-category'
  )
);
```

and to make all this happen on plugin activation take a look at [**`register_activation_hook`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook)